# Update records with different values in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to save myself a lot of queries, I'm using Mongoose as ODM.

I have a rather large array topic_codes, say 50k+ elements, I'm doing this (CoffeeScript):

```
  conditions = code: $in: topic_codes
  update     = $push: samples: date: point_in_time, volume: ??
  options    = multi: true
  TopicArchive.update conditions, update, options, (err) ->
```

Here I am trying to insert a new subdocument in '*samples*', which is an **array**, of my document with an object with two attributes, *date* and *volume*.

While **date** is the same for every record I'd like to update, **volume** it's not and can vary from record to record.

Is there a way to achieve my goal without having to go through a huge database hit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A multi update updates all matching documents according to the update specifier. If you want to update each document with a different value, then you must issue N updates for N documents (or, more precisely, N updates for each of the N update specifiers you will use). For example, if you have many fewer `volume`s than `topic_codes`, you can issue a series of multi-updates, where each update only touches those documents which should have the same `volume`, using `$in` as you already are.

Comment: doing the update grouping the array by volume seems a good idea.